Wild part of the conductor of a hyperelliptic curve does not change when passing through a tame extension
Let $C/K$ be a hyperelliptic curve over a $p$-adic field $K$. I know its conductor exponent at a prime $\mathfrak q$ of $K$, which I denote by $$n_{\mathfrak q,K}=n_{\text{tame},K}+n_{\text{wild},K}$$
and it is composed of a tame and a wild part.
Suppose that $L/K$ is a tamely ramified extension. By computing some examples, I have the impression that
$$n_{\text{wild},L}:=e(L/K)n_{\text{wild},K}$$
where $e(L/K)$ is the ramification index of $L/K$.
I know how to show that $n_{\text{wild},K}=0$ implies $n_{\text{wild},L}=0$. I am looking for a reference or proof for the more general statement (i.e. for any value of $n_{\text{wild},K}$).
Is this true more generally for any curve (not necessarily hyperelliptic)?

This is true for any continuous, finite-dimensional $\ell$-adic Galois representation $V$ when $\ell \neq p$ and follows from the general theory of Galois representations of local field.
Indeed, the formula for the wild conductor exponent is (following Definition 3.1.27 (iii) in Gabor Wiese’s notes)
$$n_w(V)=\int_0^{\infty}{\dim{V/V^{G_K^u}}\, du}.$$
Let $\eta_{L/K}$ be Herbrand’s function (as introduced in Definition 3.1.14 of the notes). Since $L/K$ is tamely ramified with index $e$, one has, for any $u>0$, $\eta_{L/K}(u)=u/e$.
Let $M/L$ be any finite extension. For any $u>0$, by Proposition 3.1.19 and Definition 3.1.22 in the notes, for any $u>0$, one has $$Gal(M/K)^u \cap Gal(M/L)=Gal(M/K)_{\eta^{-1}_{M/K}(u)} \cap Gal(M/L)=Gal(M/L)_{\eta^{-1}_{M/L}(\eta^{-1}_{L/K}(u))}=Gal(M/L)^{\eta^{-1}_{L/K}(u)},$$ whence $G_K^u \cap G_L=G_L^{\eta^{-1}_{L/K}(u)}=G_L^{ue}$.
Hence $$n_w(V)=\int_0^{\infty}{\dim{V/V^{G_K^u}}\, du}=\int_0^{\infty}{\dim{V/V^{G_L^{eu}}}\, du}=e^{-1}\int_0^{\infty}{\dim{V/V^{G_L^u}}\, du}=e^{-1}n_w(V_{|G_L}), $$ QED.

Hi @Aphelli, thanks for the proof. I came back to it and I have a few questions. 1) would it be possible to give more details about what the integral means in terms of $[G_K^0:G_K^i]$ (I found a more explicit formula in terms of lower ramification groups but cannot figure out how it would translate in upper ramification groups). 2) why are the second and third equalities true in the last statement?


this formula is the equivalent of the usual sum of codimensions divided by $[G_0:G_i]$. The point of upper ramification is precisely to normalize the ramification group numbering differently to remove this explicit dependence on the $[G_0:G_i]$ or in the “big finite field extension” in the formula.



the third inequality is just a change of variables. For the second inequality, we need to check (which I indeed forgot) that $G_K^u = G_K^u \cap G_L$ (since the RHS is equal to $G_L^{eu}$ by the answer). In other words, we need to check that $G_K^u\subset G_L$ for $u>0$. Indeed, the image of $G_K^u$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is a $p$-group contained in the inertia subgroup, hence is trivial, since $L/K$ is tamely ramified. Thus $G_K^u \subset G_L$ and we are done.


Thanks for the prompt reply. 2) Makes a lot of sense! For 1) I was more asking how I should interpret this integral. Is it the case that dim $V/V^{G^u}$ is like a step function which takes fixed values in intervals $[u_i,u_{i+1}]$ and hence the integral is simply the sum over $i$ of $(u_{i+1}-u_i)\text{dim} V/V^{G^i}$? Thanks and sorry if this is a naive question!


$u \mapsto \dim{V/V^{G^u}}$ is a non-increasing function taking its values in the positive integers. I don’t recall if it’s right- or left-continuous, but the point is that it’s piecewise constant, and the pieces are of the form $[u_i,u_{i+1})$ (or $(u_i,u_{i+1}]$ if it’s left-continuous).

